# After server move a query doesn't work anymore

Tags: sql, asp-classic, sql-server-express

I need some help for a problem that's driving me crazy!

I've moved an ASP + SQL Server application from an old server to a new one.

The old one was a Windows 2000 server with MSDE, and the new one is a Windows 2008 with SQL Server 2008 Express.

Everything is ok, even a little faster, except just one damned function whose asp page gives a time out.

I've tried the query within that page in a management query windows and it never ends, while in the old server it took about 1 minute to be completed.

The query is this one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    TBL1.TBL1_ID, 
    REPLACE(TBL1_TITOLO, CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), ’ ’), 
    COALESCE(TBL1_DURATA, 0), TBL1_NUMERO, 
    FLAG_AUDIO 
FROM 
    SPOT AS TBL1 
INNER JOIN 
    CROSS_SPOT AS CRS ON CRS.TBL1_ID = TBL1.TBL1_ID 
INNER JOIN 
    DESTINATARI_SPOT AS DSP ON DSP.TBL1_ID = TBL1.TBL1_ID 
WHERE 
    DSP.PTD_ID_PUNTO = 1044 
    AND DSP.DSP_FLAG_OK = 1 
    AND TBL1.FLAG_AUDIO_TESTO = 1 
    AND TBL1.FLAG_AUDIO_GRAFICO = ’A’ 
    AND CRS.CRS_STATO > 2 
    OR TBL1.TBL1_ID IN (SELECT ID 
                        FROM V_VIEW1 
                        WHERE ID IS NOT NULL AND V_VIEW1.ID_MODULO = 403721) 
    OR TBL1.TBL1_ID IN (SELECT TBL1_ID 
                        FROM V_VIEW2 
                        WHERE V_VIEW2.ID_PUNTO = 1044)  
ORDER BY 
    TBL1_NUMERO
```

I've tried to transform the 2 views in last lines into tables and the query works, even if a little slower than before.

I've migrated the db with it's backup/restore function. Could it be and index problem?
Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Alessandro

Comment: It is not possible to answer this without very specific details like the query plan, schema and even data. I suggest you read about query optimization in general.

Comment: suggest you start with the query plan

Comment: Were these indexed views on the old server, are they indexed now?

Answer (score 2):

Run:

```
--Defrag all indexes
sp_msForEachTable 'DBCC DBREINDEX (''?'')'

--Update all statistics
sp_msForEachTable 'UPDATE STATISTICS ? WITH FULLSCAN'
```

If that doesn't "just fix it", it's going to some subtle "improvement" in the SQL Server optimizer that made things worse.

Try the index tuning wizard (or whatever its SSMS2008 equivalent).

After that, you'll have to start picking the query apart, removing things until it runs fast. Since you have 2 `OR` clauses, you basically have 3 separate queries:

```
SELECT ... FROM ...
WHERE DSP.PTD_ID_PUNTO = 1044 
AND DSP.DSP_FLAG_OK = 1 
AND TBL1.FLAG_AUDIO_TESTO=1 
AND TBL1.FLAG_AUDIO_GRAFICO=’A’ 
AND CRS.CRS_STATO>2 

--UNION

SELECT ... FROM ...
WHERE TBL1.TBL1_ID IN (
   SELECT ID 
   FROM V_VIEW1 
   WHERE ID IS NOT NULL 
   AND V_VIEW1.ID_MODULO = 403721
) 

--UNION 

SELECT ... FROM ...
WHERE TBL1.TBL1_ID IN (
   SELECT TBL1_ID 
   FROM V_VIEW2 
   WHERE V_VIEW2.ID_PUNTO = 1044
)
```

See which one of those is the slowest.

p.s. A query taking a minute is pretty bad. My opinion is that queries should return instantly (within the limits of human observation)